# Perform segue when Push Notification opens App

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, notifications, swift2

I'm trying to redirect the user to a ViewController when he touches the Push Notification. This is working fine when the user has the App open in background, but it's not working when it has to open the App.

After some research, I have learned when the App opens due tu a push notification, it only reads the "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions".

So, I assume now I need to make some "if" statement to make the segue when the push notification is set, but I don't know how to detect the push notification because it's my first time using notifications in my app.

Here is my code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    Parse.setApplicationId(MY_APP_ID, clientKey: MY_CLIENT_KEY)

    // Registramos la Push Notification
    if application.applicationState != UIApplicationState.Background {

        let preBackgroundPush = !application.respondsToSelector("backgroundRefreshStatus")
        let oldPushHandlerOnly = !self.respondsToSelector("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:")
        var pushPayload = false
        if let options = launchOptions {
            pushPayload = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] != nil
        }
        if (preBackgroundPush || oldPushHandlerOnly || pushPayload) {
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
        }
    }

    if application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
    else {
        //let types = UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound
        //application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
        // Access the storyboard and fetch an instance of the view controller
    }

    // Change navigation bar appearance
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(hex: 0x00B7BB)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()]
    if let barFont = UIFont(name: "Avenir Next", size: 20.0) {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor(), NSFontAttributeName:barFont]
    }
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent

    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    installation.saveInBackground()
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    if error.code == 3010 {
        print("Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.")
    } else {
        print("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error)
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)

    if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
        PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
    }

    // Access the storyboard and fetch an instance of the view controller
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("UltimaMarca")

    // Then push that view controller onto the navigation stack
    let rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
    rootViewController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}
```

Do you know some tutorial, guideline or code to show me? Because I have found some lines of code in Objective-C but they are very old and I cannot use it.

Thanks,

Comment: didReceiveRemoteNotification must be invoked anyway. are you sure it's not? did you try to set a breakpoint to this method?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Hi @heximal, yes it is invoked, but I don't know how to make the if statement when the notification push opens the app.

Comment: Hi @FarhadNezhad, I didn't get any error, I just don't know how to handle the notification push in my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. Regards.

Comment: what is the sequence? didReceiveRemoteNotification first invoked and didFinishLaunchingWithOptions second? then add some boolean property to your app delegate class, init it with false in declaration, assign true to it inside didReceiveRemoteNotification and check if it's true inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: @Jordi I tried to edit out your client and application keys, but it says it's only visible to me until it's peer reviewed.  While they are obtainable from decompiling your app, you should still try to protect them as best as possible. With those keys, anyone can make requests to your app and get any data you haven't secured with ACLs and CPLs. I suggest you change your keys in your Parse settings.

Comment: Don't worry, they aren't the real ones @JakeT.